# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Box3)`, expected a ReactNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to render data with the Redux toolkit but get error like this 'Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Box3)`, expected a ReactNode', please help so that the code can be fixed and run smoothly

```
<MiniTitle>Berita Terkini</MiniTitle>
<List sx={{ width: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: { xs: "column", md: "row" } }}>
  {dataArticle.map((obj, index) => (
    <ListItem key={index}>
      <ListItemButton
        alignItems="center"
        sx={{
          width: "100%",
          padding: { sm: "10px 0px", md: "25px" },
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          flexDirection: "column",
        }}
      >
        <ListItemDecorator
          sx={{
            maxWidth: { sm: "225px", md: "900px" },
            maxHeight: { sm: "400px", md: "1600px" },
            margin: "0px",
            marginBottom: { sm: "10px", md: "20px" },
          }}
        >
          <img src={`${BASE_URL}images/${obj.featuredImage}`} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", borderRadius: "10px" }} />
        </ListItemDecorator>
        <ListItemContent
          sx={{
            width: "100%",
            display: "flex",
            textAlign: "center",
            margin: { sm: "0px 60px", md: "30px 0px" },
            fontSize: "15px",
            fontWeight: "600",
          }}
        >
          {obj.title}
        </ListItemContent>
      </ListItemButton>
    </ListItem>
  ))}
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: dataArticle.map is not a function...` implies that the value `dataArticle` is the variable that stores the fetched data from your "Database", which could be `undefined` before the data is finished fetching from you API call.

Since the method `map()` only exists in an Array object, the error can be thrown when the value is `undefined`.

What you need to do is to safeguard the component to NOT render the `dataArticle.map` part unless either the fetch is completed, or `dataArticle` has valid data.

This can be achieved by lightly modifying your code to

```
<MiniTitle>Berita Terkini</MiniTitle>
<List sx={{ width: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: { xs: 'column', md: 'row' } }}>
    {!dataArticle
        ? 'Loading Article' // avoid rendering when dataArticle isn't ready
        : dataArticle.map((obj, index) => (
              <ListItem key={index}>
                  <ListItemButton
                      alignItems="center"

                    {/* ...your original code here */}

                  </ListItemButton>
              </ListItem>
          ))}
</List>
```